# Совершение действия при одновременном нажатии Ctrl+Enter.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть HTMЛ:

```
<div>
  <div class="text-td" contenteditable="true">Ячейка</div>
  <div class="ok-td">Кнопка</div>
</div>
```

Необходимо, при одновременном нажатии Ctrl+Enter нажатии, редактируя ячейку с классом "text-td", совершить нажатие на кнопку с классом "ok-td":

```
$(this).parent().find(".ok-td").click();
```

Прочел вот этот ресурс:
http://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Работающий код:
http://learn.javascript.ru/play/tutorial/browser/events/multikeys.html

У них дана вот эта функция:

```
runOnKeys(
  function() { alert("Привет!") },
  "Q".charCodeAt(0),
  "W".charCodeAt(0)
);
```

Я сделал для своего случая, тоже работает:

```
runOnKeys(
  function() { alert("Привет!") },
  13,
  17
);
```

НО проблема в том, что блоки у меня создаются "на лету", т.е. изначально их нет, они приходят АЯКСОМ, а значит необходима функция "`.on`".

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
$("body").on("keypress", ".text-td", function(e) {      
    if(e.keyCode==13){              
          $(this).parent().find(".ok-td").click();
        }
  });
```

Она работает, если нажимаешь Enter, но мне нужно сумму Ctrl+Enter. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее можно попробовать использовать свойство ctrlKey объекта event

```
$("body").on("keypress", ".text-td", function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).parent().find(".ok-td").click();
  }
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1684236

Comment: Спасибо. А как сделать, чтобы находясь на странице, я мог из любого места при нажатии Ctrl+F, к примеру, появлялся  `alert("Привет!")`?

Comment: @bitrixoid, ваш код не будет работать в webkit-браузерах и IE. Событие должно быть или **keyup**, или **keydown**. Во-вторых, в jQuery рекомендуется использовать свойство **which**, а не keyCode.

Comment: Я делаю для себя, работаю в мазиле. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии была реакция?

Comment: @Максим147, в FF у вас и так "реакция" должна быть. А если вы по второму своему вопросу, то делаем по тому же принципу, только заменяем код клавиши.

    $("body").on("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 70) {
            alert('Привет!');
        }
    });

Comment: еще раз спасибо. Все работает! Вы программист от Бога!